# pass argument from subscribe block or error block to 'finally' block

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular9, subscriber

Is there a  way to  pass argument from subscribe block or error block to 'finally' block  without using this keyword. My attempt below which does not work

```
this.service.create()
    .pipe(first())
    .subscribe (
    (resp) => {
        let argumentToFinally = '';
        if (!!resp.taskInfo) {
            argumentToFinally = this.showError(resp.taskInfo);
        } else {
            close();
            // if else block, 'argumentToFinally' is still ''
        }
    },
    (error) => {
        this.isCallingApi = false;
        argumentToFinally = this.showError('create', undefined, error);
    },
    (argumentToFinally) => {
        close(argumentToFinally)
    });

close(argumentOfFinally?: any) {
    if (!!argumentOfFinally) {
        ..
    }
    this.closeWizard();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can only use the global variable (this.variableName) in the `finally` block as the `finally` block doesn't accept any argument.
- The `finally` block will not be called after the `error` block because the subscription is canceled when an error occurs.

For more info check -> [Using observables to pass values](https://angular.io/guide/observables)